# Export a VBA module from an Access project to an Excel project using VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I've been tasked with creating a VBA based system that will allow me to insert department specific documentation comment codes into a VBA based program and then later extract these later date.The program does this by temporarily inserting 2 VBA modules into the target project and then running the contained functions. This on it's own functions properly and the comments are inserted/extracted using VBA.

However I find myself at a loss for inserting the modules into an excel based project from  my access based insertion project. I've been importing the module to the targeted access project using this function:

```
Public Function InsertVADER(strTestPath As String, ProgramType As String) As Boolean
'//Insert VADER into the target program
On Error GoTo errjordan

Dim obj As AccessObject '//Create instance of Access Application object.

If ProgramType = "Access" Then


    ''//Transfer Modules to target project.

    For Each obj In CurrentProject.AllModules
       DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", strTestPath, acModule, obj.Name, obj.Name & "_TMP", False
    Next obj

    '//Set and open target project
    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase strTestPath, False

    '//SEt to visible. If the project has an auto exec that will usurp this project. You will
    appAccess.Visible = True


    '//Open the vader module. If there is an auto run macro this will cause it to show
    appAccess.DoCmd.OpenModule ("VADER_TMP")
ElseIf ProgramType = "Excel" Then
    '//Run Excel routine
    For Each obj In CurrentProject.AllModules
       'DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Excel", strTestPath, acModule, obj.Name, obj.Name & "_TMP", False

    Next obj





End If


'//Indicate function sucess
InsertVADER = True

Exit Function   'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
errjordan:

If Err.Number = 2501 Then
    MsgBox "Project cannot be locked for viewing. Please unlock and save project before using this tool"
    Err.Clear
    InsertVADER = False
ElseIf Err.Number = 29045 Or Err.Number = 7866 Then
    MsgBox "This file is not compatible with VADER. Please convert the project to a useable format before using this tool."
    Err.Clear
    InsertVADER = False
Else
    Err.Raise Err.Number
End If


End Function
```

StrtestPath passes the file path of the target project and programtype specifies what kind of project I've selected. Both are set in an external project.

Is there a VBA based solution that will allow me to:

1. Import the modules defined by the CurrentProject.allModules into the targeted Excel project from access

   2. Remove the modules from the target Excel Project once run

Comment: You can use [VBA Extensibility](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) to modify VBA code in Excel workbook.

Comment: @chrisneilsen This is exactly what I needed to get this moving. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the link provided by in the comment @chrisneilsen I have come up with a solution that accomplishes what we have set out to do. The solution is to create a module that is blank in the excel project and then import the VBE lines located in the access module to this new excel module as a string.

Here's a snippet of the code in case anyone else runs into this:

```
Dim vbProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim codemod As VBIDE.CodeModule

Public Function InsertVADER(strTargetPath As String, ProgramType As String, strRunFunction As String) As Boolean
if programtype = "Excel" then
    '//Run Excel routine. This version is slightly more complex as the module cannot be transfered from Access to excel as a singluar object

    '//Create an instance of an Excel application object
    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    '//Open the target workbook
    appExcel.workbooks.Open (strTargetPath)
    appExcel.Visible = True

    '//If there is an on load item for excel then it will need
    Set vbProj = appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

RetryEX:        '//If the project is locked you will exit the error capture here for excel


    Debug.Print appExcel.VBE.VBProjects(1).VBComponents.Count

    '//Add modules to the excel project
    Set VBComp = vbProj.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
        VBComp.Name = "VADER_TMP"

    Set VBComp = vbProj.VBComponents("VADER_TMP")
    Set codemod = VBComp.CodeModule

    '//Capture the code in the VADER modules located in this project
    Dim strVADER As String

    LoopCount = 1
    lngLineCount = 1
    Do Until lngLineCount > Application.VBE.VBProjects(1).VBComponents("VADER").CodeModule.CountOfLines
        strVADER = strVADER & Application.VBE.VBProjects(1).VBComponents("VADER").CodeModule.Lines(lngLineCount, 1) & vbNewLine

        lngLineCount = lngLineCount + 1
    Loop

    '//Insert the captured VADER code into the Excel module
    codemod.InsertLines 1, strVADER

    '//Do the same thing with runVADER
    Set VBComp = vbProj.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
        VBComp.Name = "runVADER_TMP"

    Set VBComp = vbProj.VBComponents("runVADER_TMP")
    Set codemod = VBComp.CodeModule

    strVADER = vbNullString
    LoopCount = 1
    lngLineCount = 1
    Do Until lngLineCount > Application.VBE.VBProjects(1).VBComponents("runVADER").CodeModule.CountOfLines
        strVADER = strVADER & Application.VBE.VBProjects(1).VBComponents("runVADER").CodeModule.Lines(lngLineCount, 1) & vbNewLine

        lngLineCount = lngLineCount + 1
    Loop

    codemod.InsertLines 1, strVADER

    '//Call the function
    appExcel.Run strRunFunction

End If


'//Indicate function sucess
InsertVADER = True

Exit Function   'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
errjordan:

'//Captured error

If Err.Number = 2501 Then
    '//An access project locked for viewing
    MsgBox "Project cannot be locked for viewing. Please unlock the project and then press OK."
    Err.Clear
    Resume Next

ElseIf Err.Number = 50289 Then
    '//An excel document locked for viewing
    MsgBox "Workbook cannot be locked for viewing. Please unlock the project and then press OK."
    Err.Clear
    GoTo RetryEX

ElseIf Err.Number = 29045 Or Err.Number = 7866 Then
    '//Not excel or access
    MsgBox "This file is not compatible with VADER. Please convert the project to a useable format before using this tool."
    Err.Clear
Else
    '//Some other error!
    Err.Raise Err.Number
End If

InsertVADER = False '//If I'm here pass a failure code

End Function
```

Removal remains very similar to that of access:

```
Public Function RemoveVADER(strTargetPath As String, ProgramType As String)
'//Remove VADER from the project
    '//Target path is not used in the function but has been left in in case of future issues/expandability

If ProgramType = "Access" Then
    Set vbcom = appAccess.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents
    vbcom.Remove VBComponent:=vbcom.Item("VADER_TMP")
    vbcom.Remove VBComponent:=vbcom.Item("runVADER_TMP")

    '//Close the target program and save changes
    appAccess.Quit acQuitSaveAll

ElseIf ProgramType = "Excel" Then
    Set vbProj = appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = vbProj.VBComponents("VADER_TMP")
    vbProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
    Set VBComp = vbProj.VBComponents("runVADER_TMP")
    vbProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp

    '//Close the target program and save changes
    appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
    appExcel.Quit
End If

End Function
```